# Automatic event creation (google Apps Script)

Tags: calendar

I not a IT so sorry if what I say or what I write is stupid things.
So I'm trying to create a script in google app to create with a redundancy.

I have two questions:

1. how to select the calendar where the event will be created
2. Is it possible to repeat this event each hour?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Mainly, Apps script is strongly related with Javascript. You will need it mainly with such datatypes as Date.

1. **Selecting calendar**

   Following command returns all calendars in array:

   ```
   var calendars = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
   ```

   Thus you can access each individual calendar by doing this:

   ```
   calendars[i] where i any number between 0 and (# of calendars-1)
   ```

   For example if you want get name of 2nd calendar:

   ```
   Logger.log('name of 2nd calendar ==>' + calendars[1].getName());
   ```
2. **Hourly event**

   You can make for loop for each hour and calling `createEvent(title, startTime, endTime)` command

More commands in [Google Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)

With regards